# DLL failed when I tried to import Trainer from transformers

Tags: machine-learning, dll, nvidia, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I wanted to finetune Transformer based models on my local machine so when I tried importing trainer

```
from transformers import Trainer
```

This error popped up

**ImportError: DLL load failed while importing lib: The specified procedure could not be found.**

**RuntimeError: Failed to `import transformers.trainer` because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
DLL load failed while importing lib: The specified procedure could not be found.**

How can I resolve this error?

**Environment**

```
Anaconda
Cuda 12.3
Python 3.9.18
torch 2.1.0+cu118
torchaudio 2.1.0+cu118
torchvision 0.16.0+cu118
transformers 4.35.2
```

I tried upgrading CUDA, upgrading and downgrading transformers library, torch and its sub libraries but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can update the pyarrow package.
It's effective for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried it and it worked